# Extract numbers from string

Tags: c++, string, servlets, numbers, extract

how do i get and store two numbers from a string using **istringstream**

For eg.

> **sum from 2 to 3**
>
> i want to read and store 2 and 3 not necessarily we know the position of integers occuring

Answer (score 0):

You can read input using `std::cin`, for example.  If you know your next token is a string, give it a string:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
```

Or an int:

```
int num;
std::cin >> num;
```

You should check for eof and error states as usual.

Comment: cin will not be able to read string with whitespaces and secondly how do i get those two numbers from string??

Comment: No, by default it reads up to a whitespace.  So you read first "sum", then "from", then number, then "to", then number.

Comment: no cin don't read whitespace and i am pretty much sure about this see this  http://ideone.com/8chyAb

Comment: Yes, cin does not "read" whitespaces, i.e. they are not part of its output, it sees them as input delimiters.  If you want to preserve spaces, getline is your friend.